# Is there a method in spacy to "normalize" feminine nouns to masculine?

Tags: spacy, lemmatization, spanish

The title pretty says it all...

We are using spacy in spanish to preprocess a series of texts and we need consistent nouns across our documents.

For instance, we would need to normalize "clienta" to "cliente" and so on

```
doc = nlp('la clienta ha pedido una coca cola')
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.lemma_, token.base_form_)
```

where base_form should be some sort of a normalised, masculine version of the noun